# Deep nested iFrames inside jQuery UI tabs stay hidden in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, iframe

I've got a web application that uses iframes to load various panels into view. At times, there are jQuery UI tabs in use to bring panels to the forefront while hiding others that are not in use. In this specific instance, one of the iframes contains jQuery UI tabs, which in turn contains iframes. And in some instances, inside that iframe, an additional iframe is used to load yet another panel of software. For the most part, this all works well. However, in the instance of this fourth level iframe, in Internet Explorer, if you change jQuery UI tabs and then return to show this specific one, the innermost iframe remains whited out. Oddly, doing just about anything, such as collapsing an adjacent panel, clicking other unrelated jquery tabs elsewhere, or toggling CSS properties in the DOM Explorer will jostle the iframe back into view.

```
<html>
<body>
...
<DIV style="HEIGHT: 858px; WIDTH: 1680px">
    <IFRAME style="HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 100%" src="..." frameBorder=0 scrolling=yes></IFRAME>
</DIV>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Inside that iframe, full html (including <html> and <body> tags).

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel">
    <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

So this seems to be an obscure jQuery UI bug relating to Internet Explorer. I'd like to avoid putting some kind of code change into my jquery-ui.js file, though I haven't found a fix for it yet, so I'm looking for ideas on what I can do to "jostle" the inner iframe back into view when you click on the jQuery UI tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this fix worked when placed in the _toggle event of jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js, you should be able to place this in your own "on tab select" event, which should also get the (event, ui) arguments.

Drill down from the tab down to the third level iframe, and trigger a resize. Oddly, calling resize() on that does not fix the issue, but setting the height attribute does (I set it to zero and then back to the original height, which might be unnecessary, but I feel is proper.)

```
tabSelected: function(event, ui) {
var toShow = ui.newPanel;
//....
toShow.find('iframe').each(function () {
    var tabFrame = this;

    $(tabFrame).contents().find('iframe').each(function () {
        var workspaceFrame = this;

        $(workspaceFrame).contents().find('iframe').each(function () {
            var innerFrame = this;

            var myHeight = $(innerFrame).attr('height');
            $(innerFrame).attr('height', 0);
            $(innerFrame).attr('height', myHeight);
        });
    });
});
//....
```

Though unnecessary, I prefer copying the "this" keyword to local variables for readability.